# Error in building mongodb source code using Visual C++

Tags: c++, mongodb, visual-c++

I followed [make_vcxproj](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/buildscripts/make_vcxproj.py) comment to create Visual C++ project. I also executed:

```
scons generated-sources
```

for creating missed file. In master branch of mongo [source code](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo) when I build the project I get following error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error C2370   'kuint16max': redefinition; different storage class
>   (compiling source file
>   src\third_party\s2\base\strtoint.cc)  mongod  D:\Open
>   Source\mongo\src\third_party\gperftools-2.5\src\base\basictypes.h 74

It seems there are two global definition of `kuint16max` one in `integral_types.h` and another in `basictypes.h`. Here is main part (related to error) in  `basictypes.h` file:

```
const uint16 kuint16max = (   (uint16) 0xFFFF);
const uint32 kuint32max = (   (uint32) 0xFFFFFFFF);
const uint64 kuint64max = ( (((uint64) kuint32max) << 32) | kuint32max );

const  int8  kint8max   = (   (  int8) 0x7F);
const  int16 kint16max  = (   ( int16) 0x7FFF);
const  int32 kint32max  = (   ( int32) 0x7FFFFFFF);
const  int64 kint64max =  ( ((( int64) kint32max) << 32) | kuint32max );

const  int8  kint8min   = (   (  int8) 0x80);
const  int16 kint16min  = (   ( int16) 0x8000);
const  int32 kint32min  = (   ( int32) 0x80000000);
const  int64 kint64min =  ( (((uint64) kint32min) << 32) | 0 );
```

and in `integral_types.h`:

```
static const uint8  kuint8max  = (( uint8) 0xFF);
static const uint16 kuint16max = ((uint16) 0xFFFF);
static const uint32 kuint32max = ((uint32) 0xFFFFFFFF);
static const uint64 kuint64max = ((uint64) GG_LONGLONG(0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF));
static const  int8  kint8min   = ((  int8) 0x80);
static const  int8  kint8max   = ((  int8) 0x7F);
static const  int16 kint16min  = (( int16) 0x8000);
static const  int16 kint16max  = (( int16) 0x7FFF);
static const  int32 kint32min  = (( int32) 0x80000000);
static const  int32 kint32max  = (( int32) 0x7FFFFFFF);
static const  int64 kint64min  = (( int64) GG_LONGLONG(0x8000000000000000));
static const  int64 kint64max  = (( int64) GG_LONGLONG(0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF));
```

When I change git branch to stable branch, error still exist. So I think problem is in my build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the vcproj stuff to build MongoDB from source. It is intended for internal best-effort use by a few Windows developers. Instead, follow the build instructions in [building.md](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/docs/building.md) and build with SCons on the command line. A good Windows build command line for the master branch might look like:

`python ./buildscripts/scons.py --release -j12 --dynamic-windows --win-version-min=ws08r2 core`

But do adjust the -j value as suitable for your local system. Note also that the building.md file is slightly out of date (a fix is currently in code review), and you will need VS2015 Update 3 along with [two](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3207317/visual-c-optimizer-fixes-for-visual-studio-2015-update-3) [hotfixes](https://support.microsoft.com/en-za/help/4020481/fix-link-exe-crashes-with-a-fatal-lnk1000-error-when-you-use-wholearch).